# For loop only printing out last element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, formatting

I have a problem with the for loop. For some reason when I execute the loop it only prints out 1 element of the for loop. This is the data I have

```
lucidData = [['Dupable', '246', 'Mercedes', '25200'], ['Qilani', '240', 'Kanna', '21000'], ['MihKyle', '250', 'Mihile', '34750'], ['Goobtella', '245', 'Kanna', '27000'], ['Gosenka', '240', 'Buccaneer', '25762'], ['Eeldu', '244', 'Pathfinder', '33359'], ['YoungHanny', '249', 'Dual Blade', '36000'], ['Yumiikko', '248', 'Kanna', '32721'], ['lRollingDeep', '247', 'Adele', '29201'], ['LordPrime', '247', 'Kaiser', '33000'], ['GoiabaSama', '255', 'Demon Avenger', '964310'], ['GordoChorizo', '246', 'Dual Blade', '30387'], ['ScarletReyne', '251', 'Ark', '29651'], ['StupidGameu', '251', 'Demon Avenger', '31674'], ['TURTLESmrff', '242', 'Pathfinder', '2400'], ['Sleepybearrx', '240', 'IL Mage', '27953'], ['Wremy', '251', 'Hero', '35773'], ['woele', '245', 'Phantom', '33578'], ['Codé002', '240', 'Kanna', '22219'], ['FullSword', '250', 'Adele', '29548'], ['Ch0senAlpha', '242', 'Hero', '28521'], ['MeserMule', '254', 'Kanna', '33974'], ['KanaoSayo', '245', 'Kanna', '23000']]
```

and when I use this for loop to try and get rid of the quotes and brackets:

```
def formatting(data):
  for i in range(len(data)):
    datas = ', '.join(data[i])
  return datas

print(formating(lucidData))
```

I get only:

```
KanaoSayo, 245, Kanna, 23000
```

Which is the last element in the list of list and I don't know why or how to fix this.

My expected output is

```
Dupable, 246, Mercedes, 25200
Quilani, 240, Kanna, 21000
...
KanaoSayo, 245, Kanna, 23000
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: You overwrite `datas` in every iteration of your loop.

Comment: You should get a syntax error since your print is missing a closing brace, is this the real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the entries in the list with `,`  and then join the result with newlines.

```
def formatting(data):
    result = []
    for entry in data:
        result.append(', '.join(entry))
    return '\n'.join(result)
```

Using a generator you can write this in one line.

```
def formatting(data):
    return '\n'.join(', '.join(entry) for entry in data)
```

---

Using an index to access every element of a list in a `for` loop is an anti-pattern in Python. That's why I replaced it and iterate over the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'datas' is getting overwritten with every iteration of the loop. Hence you are getting the last value only.

Try below if you need one list of the all the elements.

```
datas = []
def formatting(data):
  for i in range(len(data)):
    datas.extend(, '.join(data[i]))
  return datas
```

print(formating(lucidData)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by others, you override the `datas` object in each iteration while you should be appending to the result from the previous iteration:

```
def formatting(data):
  datas = ''
  for elt in data:
      datas = ', '.join(elt) + '\n' + datas
  return datas
```

Note: I have also modified the looping part to directly iterate over the element instead of index-based access of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest solution I could think of:

```
    lucidData = [['Dupable', '246', 'Mercedes', '25200'], ['Qilani', '240', 'Kanna', '21000'],
                 ['MihKyle', '250', 'Mihile', '34750'], ['Goobtella', '245', 'Kanna', '27000'],
                 ['Gosenka', '240', 'Buccaneer', '25762'], ['Eeldu', '244', 'Pathfinder', '33359'],
                 ['YoungHanny', '249', 'Dual Blade', '36000'], ['Yumiikko', '248', 'Kanna', '32721'],
                 ['lRollingDeep', '247', 'Adele', '29201'], ['LordPrime', '247', 'Kaiser', '33000'],
                 ['GoiabaSama', '255', 'Demon Avenger', '964310'], ['GordoChorizo', '246', 'Dual Blade', '30387'],
                 ['ScarletReyne', '251', 'Ark', '29651'], ['StupidGameu', '251', 'Demon Avenger', '31674'],
                 ['TURTLESmrff', '242', 'Pathfinder', '2400'], ['Sleepybearrx', '240', 'IL Mage', '27953'],
                 ['Wremy', '251', 'Hero', '35773'], ['woele', '245', 'Phantom', '33578'],
                 ['Codé002', '240', 'Kanna', '22219'], ['FullSword', '250', 'Adele', '29548'],
                 ['Ch0senAlpha', '242', 'Hero', '28521'], ['MeserMule', '254', 'Kanna', '33974'],
                 ['KanaoSayo', '245', 'Kanna', '23000']]
    
    
    def formatting(data):
        for i in data:
            print(', '.join(i))
    
    
    formatting(lucidData)

# OUTPUT:
Dupable, 246, Mercedes, 25200
Qilani, 240, Kanna, 21000
MihKyle, 250, Mihile, 34750
Goobtella, 245, Kanna, 27000
...............
MeserMule, 254, Kanna, 33974
KanaoSayo, 245, Kanna, 23000
```

Comment: This works, but for my specific project it doesn't quite fit what I need. Thank you though!